# Forecast time series XGBoost model

Tags: r, xgboost

I recently come across the `library(forecastxgb)` package in R and I have some questions.

Has anybody used the package? I would like to try it out by training a model on the `train` data and test it on the `test` data and then make a forecast on unseen data. The only thing I can see is that you feed it all the data and then it makes a forecast based on this.

Here is the output from a very simple XGBoost forecast model using Google stock. I am not really sure how to interpret the results. Is the y-axis predicted probabilties? in my example the stock can either go up or down, a 1 or 0. So does the plot tell me that the forecast is between 0.3 and 0.7 probabilities?

In the model below we train the data on 338 days and test on 130 days, so the black lines are the training predictions and the blue lines are the test predition, how can I access the probabilities of the model - if I was to buy a stock using this model I would like to know if the probability of the stock going up would be greater than 0.5 etc. I would also like to feed in my own parameters for optimisation.

It would also be quite interesting to plot over this plot the actual results and see how the model performed.

Final point (general forecasting prediction question) How would I use this model (or any forecasting model) to make a decision for the following day? I would train the model Monday and obtain a prediction for Tuesday. Then re-train the model Tuesday and obtain a prediction Wednesday etc...

Questions:

How can I access the predicted probabilities
How can I feed it my own parameters (I assume the package is a wrapper for the main xgboost package
How can I plot the actual results over the predicted probabilities or even compare the xgb predictions (`ifelse xgbpreds > 0.5, 1, 0)` to the actual results

[image]
Some basic time series forecasting model:

```
rm(list=ls())
    from <- "2017-01-01"
    to <- "2018-12-01"

    library(quantmod)
    symbols <- 'GOOG'
    getSymbols(symbols, from=from, to=to, src="yahoo", adjust=TRUE)  
    colnames(GOOG) <- c("open", "high", "low", "close", "volume", "adjusted")

    GOOG$direction <- with(GOOG, ifelse(close >= open, 1, 0))

    train_date <- nrow(GOOG) *0.7
    GOOG$rsi <- RSI(lag(GOOG$close), nFast=14, nSlow = 26, nSig = 9, maType = SMA)
    GOOG$momentum <- momentum(lag(GOOG$close), n = 12)
    GOOG <- GOOG[complete.cases(GOOG), ]

    xgbtrain <- GOOG[1:train_date,]
    xgbtest <- GOOG[-c(1:train_date),]

    x_train <- xgbtrain[, 8:ncol(xgbtrain)]
    y_train <- xgbtrain[, c("direction")]

    x_test <- xgbtest[, 8:ncol(xgbtest)]
    y_test <- xgbtest[, c("direction")]




    library(forecastxgb)
    XGBmodel <- xgbar(y = ts(y_train), xreg = ts(x_train))

    plot(forecast(XGBmodel, xreg = ts(x_test)))
```